# How to override multiple variables of a array at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I override multiple variables of an array.
For example:

```
arr = [" e ", " x ", " a ", " m ", " p ", " l ", " e "]
arr[1:3] = " y  b "
```

Arr should be:

```
[" e ", " y ", " b ", " m ", " p ", " l ", " e "]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you done to try to solve this? Please post the code you've tried so we can steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heres the right way to do that

but first lets go over something:

arrays are really *lists* in python, you declare them using `name = ["value", "value", ...]`

```
lst = [" e ", " x ", " a ", " m ", " p ", " l ", " e "]
lst[1:3] = ["a", "x"]
print(lst)
```

```
>>> [' e ', 'a', 'x', ' m ', ' p ', ' l ', ' e ']
```